# threads communication

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a form with text box and button. On click of button I'm creating a thread and invoking it for some operation. once the thread completes the invoked task, I want to update the text box with the result.

any one please assist me how can I achieve this without thread clash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far simpler using .NET 4.0's `Task` class:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
    {
         return DoSomeOperation();
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
         var result = t.Result;
         this.textBox.Text = result.ToString(); // Set your text box
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can simplify this further using the new async support:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await Task.Run( () => 
    {
         // This runs on a ThreadPool thread 
         return DoSomeOperation();
    });

    this.textBox.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: well, I'd call *dubious* on "simpler". It *might* be simpler if you just used `await`, which IIRC uses sync-context by default

Comment: @MarcGravell I find this far simpler than a thread with an invoke call in it, but that's personal preference.  Good point on await - I'll add it as an option, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to manipulate your form in it's own thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, at the end of the thread operation:

```
/// ... your code here
string newText = ...

textBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    textBox.Text = newText;
});
```

The `Control.Invoke` usage uses the message-queue to hand work to the UI thread, so it is the UI thread that executes the `textBox.Text = newText;` line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BackgroundWorker`, assign the task to the `DoWork` event, and update the text box with the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Then you can start the task with `RunWorkerAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solutions showed here:

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Next time search a bit before asking.